# Formula to calculate dates

Tags: excel, date

In my Excel sheet I want to calculate the dates of begin/end of 4 weeks.
I have this formula to calculate Monday and Sunday dates based on week number entered in C9, H9 `(= C9+1)` , C23 `(=H9+1)` , H23 `(=C23+1)` :

For Mondays

```
=IF(C9<>"",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(C9,1,3))+C9*7,"")
=IF(H9<>"",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(H9,1,3))+H9*7,"")
=IF(C23<>"",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(C23,1,3))+C23*7,"")
=IF(H23<>"",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(H23,1,3))+H23*7,"")
```

For Sundays

```
=IF(C9<>"",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(C9,1,3))+C9*7+6,"")
=IF(H9<>"",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(H9,1,3))+H9*7+6,"")
=IF(C23<>"",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(C23,1,3))+C23*7+6,"")
=IF(H23<>"",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(H23,1,3))+H23*7+6,"")
```

Now, if I enter 37 in C9, Monday and Sunday for week 37 are calculated correctly as 12th and 18th Sept, while week 38 and following are wrong (18th Sep and 24th Sep). 
Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few points for consideration w.r.t. `=IF(C9<>"",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(C9,1,3))+C9*7,"")`

1. Why we are extracting Weekday when we know its Monday i.e. 2.
2. For Sunday we know its Monday + 6 days.

Probably you used the formula from the [site](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/04/29/excel-weeknum-function-convert-week-number-date/).

`=DATE(A2, 1, -2) - WEEKDAY(DATE(A2, 1, 3)) + B2 * 7` ---> Here B2 and A2 are different, while you are referring to same cell in your formula.

In your formula --- replace `WEEKDAY(DATE(H9,1,3))` with `WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 3))`. It will work.

Comment: I don't get your point. Can you rephrase? I want the user to only enter the week number, then let the sheet calculate the rest.

Comment: Is it only for 2016? If so then I will create the formula for you.

Comment: Edited the answer please see